# How do i achieve vertcal scrolling in amcharts

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013, amcharts

I want to achieve vertical scroll in my amcharts(stacked) as in the fiddle [zoomable vertical value axis](http://jsfiddle.net/5wd44rkc/2/)

The part of code responsible for this vertical scroll is as follows:

```
  "valueScrollbar": {
"autoGridCount": true,
"color": "#000000",
"scrollbarHeight": 50
},
```

but I am using different amchart coding pattern as depicted below:

```
   AmCharts.ready(function() {
                // SERIAL CHART
                chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
                chart.dataProvider = chartDataResults;
                chart.categoryField = "States";
                chart.plotAreaBorderAlpha = 0.2;
```

How do i achieve this functionality as there is no class for valuescrollbar.
I tried this:
  `var valueScrollbar = new AmCharts.valueScrollbar();`

but AmCharts.valueScrollbar() is not valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no separate value scrollbar class as it is just a `ChartScrollbar` object under the hood. All you have to do is assign the chart object's valueScrollbar property to an instance of `ChartScrollbar` or create an object similar to the JSON-style way of initialization:

```
//JSON-style setup:
chart.valueScrollbar = {
  "autoGridCount": true,
  "color": "#000000",
  "scrollbarHeight": 50
}

//OO setup
var valueScrollbar = new AmCharts.ChartScrollbar();
valueScrollbar.autoGridCount = true;
valueScrollbar.color = "#000000";
valueScrollbar.scrollbarHeight = 50;
chart.valueScrollbar = valueScrollbar;
```

Comment: xorspark-Thank you so much..! it worked well..the way i wanted it to be..:-)